# df.groupby() modification HELP needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is my table:

```
   A  B  C  E
0  1  1  5  4
1  1  1  1  1
2  3  3  8  2
```

Now, I want to group all rows by Column A and B. Column C should be summed and for column E, I want to use the value where value C is max.

I did the first part of grouping A and B and summing C. I did this with:

```
df = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].sum()
```

But at this point, I am not sure how to tell that column E should take the value where C is max.

The end result should look like this:

```
   A  B  C  E
0  1  1  6  4
1  3  3  8  2
```

Can somebody help me with this past piece?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `groupby` with `agg` after sorting by `C`.

In general, if you are applying different functions to different columns, [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) allows you to pass a dictionary specifying which operation is applied to each column:

```
df.sort_values('C').groupby(['A', 'B'], sort=False).agg({'C': 'sum', 'E': 'last'})

     C  E
A B
1 1  6  4
3 3  8  2
```

By sorting by column `C` first, and *not* sorting as part of `groupby`, we can select the last value of `E` per group, which will align with the maximum value of `C` for each group.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this! Really made my day.

Comment: When I check on the number of columns for the original VS the modified dataframe, there are differences. The original dataframe has 4 columns (A,B,C,E) and the modified one has 2 (C,E). How can I get the modified dataframe to return 4 total columns again?

Comment: @Tina, just call `reset_index()` on the result, so `df.sort_values('C').groupby(['A', 'B'], sort=False).agg({'C': 'sum', 'E': 'last'}).reset_index()`